# extracting data between [ ] with preg_match php

Tags: php, regex

i try to extract only the number beetween the [] from my response textfile:

```
$res1 = "MESSAGE_RESOURCE_CREATED Resource [realestate] with id [75739528] has been created.";
```

i use this code

```
$regex = '/\[(.*)\]/s';
preg_match($regex, $res1, $matches_arr);
echo $matches_arr[1];
```

my result is:

```
realestate] with id [75742084
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Use `.+` instead of `.*` otherwise u'll have a greedy regex

Comment: I will never understand why people do not stick to standards, and come up with their own ones.

Comment: You can simply adjust your pattern to: `/\[(\d+)\]/s` or use @zx81s solution in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$regex = '~\[\K\d+~';
if (preg_match($regex, $res1 , $m)) {
    $thematch = $m[0];
    // matches 75739528
    }
```

See the match in **[the Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/4)**.

**Explanation**

- `\[` matches the opening bracket
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\d+` matches one or more digits

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be,

```
(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/vM7wT6/9)

PHP code would be,

```
$regex = '~(?<=\[)\d+(?=\])~';
preg_match($regex, $res1, $matches_arr);
echo $matches_arr[0];
```

Output:

```
75739528
```

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER it's easy one. I matches one or more numbers which are preceeded by `[` and followed by `]`

Comment: You don't need look behinds and that kind of stuff for this task. It does the same as this much simpler regex `/\[(\d+)\]/`

Comment: `\K` and `(?<=)` does the same operation. But your regex needs capturing group. We try to solve the problem without using capturing groups.

Comment: Nope `(?<=)` is a look behind while `\K` just forgets about all consumed chars till itself. The result is maybe the same in this case but not what they both do.

Comment: yep. I know both does same operation but in php, lookbehinds won't allow `*` or `+` or `?` inside. `C#` and `.NET` regex supports this feature.

Comment: As I told you it's to complicated. I first thought this regex is very smart or something like this, but it's just too complicated for this simple task the questioner likes to solve. I'll refuse my vote if you can explain me why you use look behinds...

Comment: Why are you assuming lookbehinds makes the task so tougher? Maximum all languages supports lookbehind except javascript. But `\K` is supported by only few languages.

Comment: Because look behinds do make no sense for this simple task. And this question is tagged with `php` to it doesn't matter in which languages `\K` is supported. As long as it is supported in PHP.

Comment: PHP also supports lookbehinds. It seems complex to you only.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to match what's inside the brackets, which means that you must match everything but a closing bracket:

```
/\[([^]]+)\]/g
```

**[DEMO HERE](http://regex101.com/r/gM4pI1/6)**

Omit the g-flag in `preg_match()`:

```
$regex = '/\[([^]]+)\]/';
preg_match($regex, $res1, $matches_arr);
echo $matches_arr[1]; //will output realestate
echo $matches_arr[2]; //will output 75739528
```